# Помогите написать функцию на Python?

Tags: python, функции

Напишите функцию `rental_cost` с аргументом - количество дней. 
Эта функция должна рассчитать стоимость аренды авто, если за сутки вы должны оплачивать саму ренту (40 у.е) + стоимость услуг страхового агенства (+0,1% за каждый следующий день. 
Т.е. первый день 1%от стоимости, второй - 1% от (1% от стоимости) и т.д. Если вы арендуете на 7 дней, то скидка - 50 у.е., если на 3 дня - 20 у.е. Обе скидки получить сразу нельзя.
Вот что я попробовал и выдало ошибку

```
def rental_car_cost(days):
  plata= days*(40+40*0.01*days)
  return plata
rental_car_cost(40)
```

Comment: Во-первых, Вам нужна геометрическая прогрессия. Во-вторых, я совсем не увидел условия скидок.

Comment: берешь например на 8 дней и можешь выбрать одну из 2 скидок

Comment: Прлценты разные в вопросе. 0.1 или 1?

Comment: Неправда, данный код не выдает ошибку, а без проблем выполняется. Хотя и делает совсем не то, что требуется.